How to implement autoscale y-axis
I tried to build line chart generator in ts all is great but how to implement autoscale on the y-axis.
this class takes a svg input and Data interface
export interface Data {
    type: 'line',
    labels: (string | number)[],
    dataset: {
        label: string,
        data: number[],
        stroke?: string,
        fill?: string,
    }[];
};

this is line class that will be exported for chart class.
import { Draw } from './draw.js'
import { Data } from './chart.js';

type data = Omit<Data, 'type'>;

function scales(start: number, end: number = start, steps: number = 1): number[] {
    const range = [];
    if (start > end) {
        [start, end] = [end, start];
    }
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i += steps) {
        range.push(i);
    }
    return range;
}

export class Line extends Draw {
    private scales: number[];
    private data: data;
    readonly padding: number;
    readonly width: number;
    readonly height: number;
    readonly min: number;
    readonly max: number;
    readonly steps: number;
    constructor(svg: SVGElement, data: data) {
        super(svg);
        this.svg = svg;
        this.data = data;
        this.width = parseInt(svg.getAttribute('width') as string);
        this.height = parseInt(svg.getAttribute('height') as string);
        this.min = Math.min(...this.data.dataset.map(datum => datum.data).flat());
        this.max = Math.max(...this.data.dataset.map(datum => datum.data).flat());
        this.steps = 1;
        this.scales = scales(this.min, this.max,10);
        this.padding = this.height / 100 * 12;
    };



    // y: ((this.height - this.padding * 2) / (d.length - 1)) * (d.length - 1 - y) + this.padding;
    // y: -((this.height - this.padding * 2) / (this.scales.length - 1)) * y + this.height -  this.padding
    protected coordinate(x: number, y: number): { x: number, y: number } {
        return { x: ((this.width - this.padding * 2) / (this.data.labels.length - 1)) * x + this.padding, y: -((this.height - this.padding * 2) / (this.scales.length - 1)) * y + this.height - this.padding };
    };

    public axis() {
        const element = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
        element.appendChild(this.line(this.coordinate(0, 0).x, this.padding, this.padding, this.height - (this.padding - 10), 1.5, 'grey', 'axis'));
        element.appendChild(this.line(this.coordinate(0, 0).x, this.height - this.padding, this.width - this.padding, this.height - this.padding, 1.5, 'grey', 'axis'));
        this.svg.appendChild(element);
    }

    public gridlines() {
        const verticals = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
        // verticals
        for (let x = 0; x < this.data.labels.length; x++) {
            this.text(this.coordinate(x, 0).x, this.height - this.padding + 22, this.data.labels[x]);
            verticals.appendChild(this.line(this.coordinate(x, 0).x, this.height - this.padding, this.coordinate(x, 0).x, this.height - this.padding + 10, 1.5, 'currentColor', `${x}`));
            if (!x) continue;
            verticals.appendChild(this.line(this.coordinate(x, 0).x, this.padding, this.coordinate(x, 0).x, this.height - this.padding, undefined, 'lightgrey', `${x}`));
        }
        console.log(this.min, this.max, this.scales);

        const horizontal = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
        //horizental
        for (let y = 0; y < this.scales.length; y++) {
            this.text(this.padding - 18, this.coordinate(0, this.scales[y]).y, this.scales[y]);
            horizontal.appendChild(this.line(this.padding - 10, this.coordinate(0, this.scales[y]).y, this.padding, this.coordinate(0, this.scales[y]).y, 1.5, 'currentColor', `${y}`));
            if (y == 0) continue;
            horizontal.appendChild(this.line(this.padding, this.coordinate(0, this.scales[y]).y, this.width - this.padding, this.coordinate(0, this.scales[y]).y, undefined, 'lightgrey', `${y}`));
        }
        this.svg.append(verticals, horizontal);
    }

    public plot() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.data.dataset.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < this.data.dataset[i].data.length - 1; j++) {
                const x1 = this.coordinate(j, 0).x;
                const y1 = this.coordinate(0, this.data.dataset[i].data[j]).y;
                const x2 = this.coordinate(j + 1, 0).x;
                const y2 = this.coordinate(0, this.data.dataset[i].data[j + 1]).y;
                this.svg.appendChild(this.line(x1, y1, x2, y2, 3, this.data.dataset[i].stroke, 'plot-line'));
            }
        }
    }
}

the draw module
it contains methods for line chart.
export class Draw {
    protected svg: SVGElement;
    constructor(svg: SVGElement) {
        this.svg = svg;
    };

    protected line(x1: number, y1: number, x2: number, y2: number, width: number = 1, color: string = 'black', className: string) {
        const element = document.createElementNS<'line'>('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
        element.setAttribute('x1', `${x1}`);
        element.setAttribute('x2', `${x2}`);
        element.setAttribute('y1', `${y1}`);
        element.setAttribute('y2', `${y2}`);
        element.setAttribute('stroke-width', `${width}`);
        element.setAttribute('stroke', `${color}`);
        element.classList.value = className;
        return element;
    };

    protected circle(x: number, y: number, radius: number, color: string) {
        const element = document.createElementNS<'circle'>('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
        element.setAttribute('cx', `${x}`);
        element.setAttribute('cy', `${y}`);
        element.setAttribute('r', `${radius}`);
        element.setAttribute('fill', `${color}`);
        this.svg.appendChild(element);
    }

    protected text(x: number, y: number, text: string | number, rotate?: string): void {
        const element = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
        element.setAttribute('x', `${x}`);
        element.setAttribute('y', `${y}`);
        element.setAttribute('text-anchor', `middle`);
        element.setAttribute('alignment-baseline', `middle`);
        element.textContent = text as string;
        if(rotate){
            element.style.rotate = `${rotate}`;
            element.style.transformOrigin = `${x + 15}px ${y}px`;
            // element.style.textAlign = `center`;
        }
        this.svg.appendChild(element);
    };
}

is there something i am missing? i don't know i tried to scale it but the coordinate function will be impacted.
